# ActiveRecord Composition

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Following the single responsibility principle, I want to put some attributes and state in one separate class, but, I want it to be in the same table.

Example:

```
class Person
  attr_accessible :name, :age
end

class Measures
  attr_accessible :weight, :height, :other_attrs
end
```

How can I composite `Measures` into `Person`, storing the `Measure` data in the `persons` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord contains a specific feature for this.

```
class Person
  composed_of :measures
end
```

If the class name cannot be inferred from the declaration, add a `class_name` option.  This is not necessary in your example.  If the database columns do not map exactly to the attributes of the Measures object, add a `:mapping` option, e.g.:

```
  composed_of :measures, mapping: %w[database_column_name, object_attribute_name]
```

If you want to do something custom when a Measures is created upon retrieval, or when a new value is assigned, use the `constructor` and `converter` options, respectively, and pass them a Proc.  This is documented [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods/composed_of).

Caveats:

1. The composed of object is a VALUE object.  Don't change it's
   attributes, instead assign a new version of the object.
2. There is a move afoot to move this feature out of Rails into a gem.  The
   attempt to remove it was not successful so far and it is still in
   Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works with rails 4, but in rails 3 you can do something like

```
class Measures
  self.table_name = 'name_of_the_person_table'
  attr_accessible :weight, :height, :other_attrs
end
```

Give it a try!